# How to find top 10 most viewed and top 10 most liked data in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Post table in mongo db. There are 1000 of post in the table. I tried following query to fetch top 10 most viewed and top 10 most liked post but I don't get any expected output. How to get that output, please help me.

This is my Post model in mongo db database where made two fields for views and likes.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const postSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  likes: [User],
  views: {
    type: Number,
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "users",
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});


//Controller 

 topViewPosts(req, res) {
    try {
      Post.find()
        .sort({ views: -1 })
        .limit(10)
        .then((posts) => {
          console.log(posts);
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Fetch seccessful",
            posts: posts,
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          res.status(500).json({
            error: error,
          });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: error,
      });
    }
  },

  topLikePosts(req, res) {
    try {
      Post.find()
        .sort({ likes: -1 })
        .limit(10)
        .then((posts) => {
          console.log(posts);
          res.status(200).json({
            message: "Fetch seccessful",
            posts: posts,
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          res.status(500).json({
            error: error,
          });
        });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({
        error: error,
      });
    }
  },
```

Comment: did you consider using aggregation? Here you are doing find(), returning all the document first and then sorting on it. It is a very costly.

Comment: @ShivamPandey no, I didn't try aggregate, Can you help me with that

Answer (score 0):

use the sort property :

```js
router.get("/yourrouter",  async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const variable = await Modal.find()
            .sort(function(a,b) {
                if (a.likes > b.likes) return -1
                if (a.likes < b.likes) return 1
                return 0
            })
        res.status(200).json(post)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json(error)
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.